# How do I remove mail html content from Rails' logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

After an email has been delivered, the entire content of the email is visible in the logs in production, which is really messy. Can I remove the email content from the logs just in production?

Comment: It's also a potential security/privacy concern (depending on the nature of the emails your app sends/receives).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ActionMailer::Base.logger = nil
```

or in your config/environments/{development,test,production}.rb, add :

```
Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.action_mailer.logger = nil
  ...
end
```

Comment: not a great answer IMO since the OP asked about exlcuding one specific type of content from logs and this will prevent a ANY logging in the mailer. So just beware that if you have ANY logger.xxxx statements in your mailer, it will start throwing exceptions because logger will be nil.

Comment: This is accurate with Ruby on Rails guides. "Generates information on the mailing run if available. Can be set to nil for no logging. Compatible with both Ruby's own Logger and Log4r loggers."

Answer (score 6):

You may also consider setting the log level of your whole application in production to something less verbose than `:debug`. That way you will still log info about the mails being sent, but without the content:

```rb
# config/environments/production.rb

Rails.application.configure do
  ...
  config.log_level = :info
  ...
end
```